# Dashed input field in android for confirmation codes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-developer-api

I am trying to create a Dashed input field for numbers in android layout, such as " _ _ _ _ " where I can add 4 numbers and get them in my main activity. I have searched a lot but not getting any better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this library to achieve your objective.
https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input

Comment: i tried using this library but it doesnt work when i get data from the input fields

Comment: i was doing a mistake , it worked now . thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Create **EditText** for 4 dashes and implement **OnTextChanged()** for every **EditText** to *quickly jump to other input*. Make sure the **EditText** has **input type as number** and can only **allow a single digit**. You can create such with this concept.