# How to create a dashed input field similar to material-code-input library?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve the following;

[image]

found suggestions in different stack questions to use [material_code_input](https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input) library, But unfortunatly it has a couple of limitations and doesn't fulfill my needs, Is there is any alternatives, or How can i achieve this view using normal widgets

Comment: i think that can be accomplished by having edit text with bottom border and point next box programmatically and when user erase then point previous edit text.

Comment: yes i did so following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252247/dashed-input-field-in-android-for-confirmation-codes

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this library on your project. In activity root layout background, use an image like as in your given prototype. Hopefully it works.

https://github.com/raycoarana/material-code-input